# react-masonry-component not centered in the parent div

Tags: html, css, reactjs, npm

I am using the npm react-masonry-component to create a masonry like grid for my page. I can't figure out how to get the grid to be centered within the parent element.

I have a demo version set up on codesandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/condescending-moon-txk0j?file=/src/styles.scss)

Comment: this is what you need? https://masonry.desandro.com/options.html#fitwidth

Comment: yeah thats right

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just set `isFitWidth: true` to the options you pass to the Masonry Component, as you can see [in this forked codepen](https://codesandbox.io/s/dawn-lake-hli6n-2-forked-t3y5w)

```
  const masonryOptions = {
    transitionDuration: 0,
    fitWidth: true // <-- this option will do the job
  };

  return (
    <section id="artists">
      <Masonry
        options={masonryOptions}
        className={"my-gallery-class masonry"}
        elementType={"ul"}
        disableImagesLoaded={false}
        updateOnEachImageLoad={false}
      >
```